# Ionic 2 - Redirect to Login Page is Firebase Auth doesnt exist

Tags: firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-realtime-database, ionic2, firebase-authentication

I checked on finding a solid solution to this ages ago but didnt really come up with anything so thought I would revisit it again. Is there a solid way to authenticate a user in an Ionic2 app and if the users not logged in or their Firebase auth goes/expires to block them from accessing any other pages - Ionic2 doesnt seem to have a nice Auth/Route Guard like Angular 2 so just wondering what the story with this is now, I know there is lifecycle hooks but again it doesnt seem to solid to me to have to call this in ever component - to me a service might be better to check for firebase auth token and if its not there then to set the route page

Comment: why dont try this `this.af.auth.subscribe` if there is an user is logged in if not go login again, im using that to keep sesion alive if the user already logged in

Comment: But does this have to be called on every Page ? and if not how do you handle the redirect from within the service ?

Comment: no, just do it on your app.component and in the other pages just do login or signout.

Comment: Very good - I actually figured it out in the end too. Im using Events to pub and sub in the app component and a service